# Guard a section of code from being executed concurrently in a coroutine

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to protect a section of code from being executed concurrently in a coroutine. Guarding against concurrent execution in a multithreaded environment would be a simple matter of using the [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) class template. My coroutine, however, is called from a single thread, so that solution is not applicable.

The following is (pseudo) code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
future<http_response> send_req_async(http_request req) {
    while (true) {
        // Attempt to send an HTTP request
        auto const& access_token{ token_store::access_token() };
        auto const response{ co_await impl::send_req_async(req, access_token) };
        if (response.status_code() == http_code::ok) {
            co_return response;
        }

        // Attempt to refresh access token
        if (response.status_code() == http_code::unauthorized) {
            // The following scope needs to be guarded against concurrent execution.
            // To guard against concurrent execution from multiple threads I would use:
            // lock_guard<mutex> guard(refresh_token_mutex);
            if (access_token != token_store::access_token()) {
                continue;
            }
            auto const& token{ co_await refresh_token(token_store::refresh_token()) };
            token_store::save_access_token(token);
            // End of section that needs to be guarded.
        }
    }
}
```

The code is meant to allow for several requests being issued in parallel, while allowing only a single coroutine invocation from trying to refresh an expired access token. Ideally, a solution should suspend a concurrent coroutine invocation, while a token refresh operation is in flight, and automatically resume it afterwards (i.e. the same semantics of `std::lock_guard` in a multithreading environment).

Is there anything built into the coroutine machinery or the C++ Standard Library that allows me to implement this in a clean fashion, or will I have to roll my own?

---

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2, so you can assume full support for C++17, plus its Coroutine TS implementation.

Comment: co-routine aren't concurrent

Comment: @Tyker: Once a coroutine hits a suspend-point, control is transferred back to the caller, which can issue another call to the same coroutine. They do not run in parallel, like threads do, but multiple concurrent executions are indeed possible.

Comment: I think you need another level of indirection around token refresh. Each send_req_async execution would need to subscribe to some "there is a new token on its way" subprocess/coroutine.

Comment: So what semantics do you require? What should a co-routine _do_ if it wants to refresh the access token, but discovers another (suspended) coroutine has already started doing it? Can it yield and resume once the new token is available? Should it abort and retry?

Comment: @Useless: It should wait, until that other invocation has run to completion, and then continue executing. Pretty much what the `lock_guard` does in a multithreading environment.

Comment: Easy, you need an async lock. a lock you can `co_await` on `mtx.lock_async`

Comment: @DavidHaim: Is there anything pre-built in the C++ Standard Library, or would I have to write my own awaitable?

Comment: @IInspectable Oh no, it's C++. we don't have it in the standard. luckily there are many implementations on Github, both in C++ and C# (which you can port to C++)

Comment: @DavidHaim: Great, thank you. Of course, Lewis Baker has an [async_mutex](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#async_mutex) implementation, which looks to be just what I was looking for. I'll see how that pans out.

Comment: @DavidHaim: That was a lot easier than expected. Once incorporated, using Lewis Baker's `async_mutex` was remarkably simple. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no infrastructure provided by C++ or the Standard Library to get the required functionality. However, the [Coroutine TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4649.pdf) provides the building blocks to implement a `co_await`-able async mutex.

The general idea is to implement an awaitable, that tries to acquire a suitable mutex when evaluating the `await_suspend` expression. If the lock cannot be acquired, the coroutine is suspended and added to a queue of awaiters, otherwise execution continues immediately (with the lock being held).

The mutex' `unlock` method resumes an awaiter from the queue, unless the queue of awaiters is empty.

There are pre-built solutions on the web. I went with Lewis Baker's [`async_mutex`](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#async_mutex) implementation for a number of reasons:

- No external of internal dependencies. Just drop the compilation unit and header file into your project and you are done.
- The lock is owned by the coroutine, not a thread. The implementation allows for a coroutine to resume on a different thread.
- It's a lock-free implementation.

Use of this implementation is very similar to that of a `std::lock_guard`:

```
#include <cppcoro/async_mutex.hpp>

namespace {
    cppcoro::async_mutex refresh_mutex;
}

future<http_response> send_req_async(http_request req) {
    while (true) {
        // Attempt to send an HTTP request
        auto const& access_token{ token_store::access_token() };
        auto const response{ co_await impl::send_req_async(req, access_token) };
        if (response.status_code() == http_code::ok) {
            co_return response;
        }

        // Attempt to refresh access token
        if (response.status_code() == http_code::unauthorized) {
            // The following scope needs to be guarded against concurrent execution.
            auto const refresh_guard{ co_await refresh_mutex.scoped_lock_async() };
            if (access_token != token_store::access_token()) {
                continue;
            }
            auto const& token{ co_await refresh_token(token_store::refresh_token()) };
            token_store::save_access_token(token);
            // refresh_guard falls out of scope, unlocking the mutex.
            // If there are any suspended coroutines, the oldest one gets resumed.
        }
    }
}
```