# Hololens camera video capture not starting in UWP

Tags: uwp, camera, hololens, c++-winrt

I have an application written in UWP (C++/WinRT) - no Unity, on Hololens. The application attempts to start video capture from the front camera like this:

```cpp
IAsyncAction Init()
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_lock);

   m_mediaCapture = MediaCapture();
   m_mediaCapture.Failed([this](auto&& sender, auto&& args)
   { /* log the error */ });

   MediaCaptureInitializationSettings mcis;
   mcis.StreamingCaptureMode(StreamingCaptureMode::Video);
   mcis.MediaCategory(MediaCategory::Media);
   mcis.MemoryPreference(MediaCaptureMemoryPreference::Cpu);

   co_await m_mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mcis);
   co_return;   
}
```

```cpp
IAsyncAction Start(const MediaCapture& mc)
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_lock);

   for (auto src: mc.FrameSources())
   {
      MediaFrameSource source = src.Value();
      MediaFrameSourceInfo info = source.Info();

      if(IsTheCameraIWant(info))
      {
         m_reader = mc.CreateFrameReaderAsync(source).get();
         m_reader.AcquisitionMode(MediaFrameReaderAcquisitionMode::Realtime);
         m_reader.FrameArrived([this](auto&& mfr, auto&& args){ HandleCapturedFrame(mfr, args); });
      }
   }

   co_return;
}
```

```cpp
void HandleCapturedFrame(const MediaFrameReader &reader, const MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs& args)
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_lock);
   auto frame = reader.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
   // do something with the frame
   frame.Close();
}
```

The problem is, that starting the camera is not reliable. When I deploy the app to Hololens, or make it run from VS, the camera initializes and works just fine. When I close the app and reopen, `Start` executes without exception, but then the `MediaCapture.Failed` handler fires with the message `A media source cannot go from the stopped state to the paused state.`. The privacy camera LED on Hololens is also not lit and I get no video frames. A redeploy from VS or restarting Hololens helps, but gives me one or two successful initializations and then the failures start again.

When the application is shutting down, I do `co_await m_reader.StopAsync()`, `m_reader.Close()` and `m_mediaCapture.get().Close()`, I cannot think of any more cleanup to be done.

Does anyone have an idea how to get consistent camera inits? Maybe some cleanup I may be forgetting...

Comment: Are you sure the stopping and closing is actually completed before it's shutting down? Maybe try to add some debug messages with the statuses of it all.

Comment: @HoloLady: yes, I do the cleanup (async calls are co_awaited), wait for an additional 1 second and then execute `CoreApplication::Exit()` to kill the app

Comment: And if you just run it one time with an additional 20 seconds delay, just to check if that's not it?

Comment: @HoloLady: unfortunately, 20 seconds did not resolve it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error using the Camera resolution sample (C++) from Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples (https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution) but failed. 
I closed the app and reopened it, and everything worked as expected.
But the difference is that the sample starts transmitting video frames after the user clicks the initialization button. So, in which state of the life cycle does your application start transmitting video frames? Initializing MediaCapture in the wrong state may be the cause of the error.

Comment: In addition, you can try to fix your app with this sample. If the error still occurs, could you tell us which device are you using for test and which OS version of it so that we can locate the problem?

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I start video capture very early, log shows within a second of app startup. I will try delaying it. My OS build on Hololens 1 is 10.0.17769.737, FW revision 0005.05.S.1801091036R, the C++ project uses the platform version 10.0.17134.0.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT we're getting somewhere - I added a 3 second delay to the camera startup and now it starts up reliably. Any idea, why this is so? Not that I'm complaining.

Comment: It seems that your FramReader started working before the camera was started. Does your code contain the logic to block the next code before the camera is initialized and coroutine is returned ? If it can be solved, this may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT my `Init` function co-awaits `MediaCapture::InitializeAsync` before trying to acquire the frame reader. And in `Start` the we wait fro the creation of the FrameReader before trying to start it. Is there any way to wait for the camera to start up as you say?

Comment: I used Camera Face Detection Sample(https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFaceDetection) to reproduce your problem, the camera won't work after restarting the app. I tried to kill "HoloCameraApp.exe" in the device portal after closing the app, then the app would open reliably. Can your app be temporarily fixed using this way?

Comment: Here are some guesses about the cause: it seems to be the state machine of system camera returned the unreliable information, it returns the Ready signal on the second call without waiting for the camera to resume.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT yes, killing HoloCameraApp.exe does the trick, as well.

Comment: HI, we noticed that you asked the same question at the Assisted Support. Engineer James has contacted you. In order to protect your privacy, we recommend that you discuss it in the Assted Support.

Comment: This may not immediately be related to your issue, but you are using a synchronization primitive, that's incompatible with coroutines. When `lock()`ed, a `std::mutex` is owned by a thread. However, coroutines do not have thread affinity. A coroutine can suspend on one thread, and resume on a different thread. You'll need to use a synchronization primitive that accommodates for this, like [async_mutext](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#async_mutex). See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50580792/1889329) for an example use case.

Comment: @IInspectable - I didn't realize that, but it makes sense now that you mention it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?