# Is there any specification on c++20 coroutine with std::mutex

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

Does C++20 coroutine have any specification on coroutine with `std::mutex`? Is it problematic to use `std::mutex` in a coroutine? If it is, is there any solution?

The following are 3 examples (I'm quite new to a coroutine, correct me if I'm wrong).

#### Example 1: coroutine with std::mutex and blocking operation

In a coroutine, we need to do a blocking operation with a lock, so that no multiple coroutines do the job at the same time.

```
task<> with_mutex_and_blocking_op() {
    Result result;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(some_non_recursive_mutex);  // ensure there's only one coroutine calls `call_blocking_io`

        result = call_blocking_io();   // block here until IO finishes
    }

    co_await some_awaiter(result);
}
```

#### Example 2: coroutine with std::mutex

We can start an async operation in `await_suspend`, and get its result in `await_resume`. The async operation submits a task to a task queue, and the queue is protected by a `std::mutex`, or gets some lock-protected resources for the async operation.

```
void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
    auto task = create_an_async_task();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(some_non_recursive_mutex);

    task_queue.push(std::move(task));
}
```

#### Example 3: coroutine with `std::mutex` protecting a co_await

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580792/guard-a-section-of-code-from-being-executed-concurrently-in-a-coroutine) is a similar problem with *Example 1*, except that the critical section calls `co_await`.

#### Some ideas

*Example 1* seems like an anti-pattern, i.e. calling a blocking function in a coroutine, but I'm wondering what will happen? Say coroutine A acquires the mutex and calls `call_blocking_io`. Since it's blocking, I think the scheduler will switch to another coroutine, e.g. coroutine B. Unfortunately, B is scheduled on the same thread as coroutine A and tries to lock the mutex. This results in the same thread trying to lock the non-recursive mutex twice, and its undefined behavior.

*Example 2* tries to lock the mutex in `await_suspend`. If it cannot acquire the lock, it will block. In this case, does the scheduler switch to another coroutine? If it will be switched, I think it has the same problem as *Example 1*.

*Example 3* already has an answer and a solution. I'm wondering, 4 years passed if it's still the case? Does C++ 20 release some feature to solve it?

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: There's a single question, except I give 3 examples. Does c++ coroutine works with std::mutex?

Comment: The first paragraph literally contains 3 separate questions. And each of them seems to be rather broad and unrelated to the examples below. Each of the examples probably deserves its own question as well.

Comment: note that 4 years passed since the other answer has been posted, though this was only 2 years before 2020, in a time where it was more or less settled what will be in C++20. If I pick one question "Does C++20 coroutine have any specification on coroutine with std::mutex?" then I think the answer you link already answers that

Comment: Coroutines are not scheduled, threads are. So if a thread is blocking, it will not suddenly start working on something else.

Comment: "*the queue is protected by a std::mutex, or get some lock protected resources for the async operation.*" Then the async operation should be the one who locks the mutex.

Comment: @BoP So if the thread is blocked, either by trying to get a lock or an IO operation, no other coroutine can run in the same thread? If that's true, the problem I described in the first two examples won't happen, and we can safely use `std::mutex` with coroutine, right?

Comment: Yes, using a mutex would work.

Comment: In your case, it works. But calling lock on a mutex, with a suspension following it, does not. Another coroutine could try to lock the mutex which is then indeed UB.